# Understanding exception inside linux kernel

Tags: linux, exception, linux-kernel, embedded

I am trying to debug our embedded linux system under very low temperatures (<40C). The problem is that it does not always boot correctly and I am trying to figure out why. After some analysis I saw that the kernel goes into panic during the start-up with the following output:

```
can: controller area network core (rev 20090105 abi 8)
NET: Registered protocol family 29
can: raw protocol (rev 20090105)
/opt/elinos-5.1/linux/linux-ppc-2.6.34/drivers/rtc/hctosys.c: unable to open rtc
 device (rtc0)
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
IP-Config: Complete:
     device=eth0, addr=192.168.100.100, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=255.255.255.255,
     host=192.168.100.100, domain=, nis-domain=(none),
     bootserver=192.168.100.20, rootserver=192.168.100.20, rootpath=
Freeing unused kernel memory: 156k init
init started: BusyBox v1.6.1 (2013-06-03 11:53:03 CEST) multi-call binary
ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
udevd-work[84]: '/sbin/modprobe -bv of:NioctlT<NULL>Cfsl,mpc5125-ioctl' unexpect
ed exit with status 0x000b

------------[ cut here ]------------
Badness at /opt/elinos-5.1/linux/linux-ppc-2.6.34/kernel/sched.c:3574
NIP: c001acfc LR: c001ace4 CTR: c01c5fa4
REGS: c790f7c0 TRAP: 0700   Not tainted  (2.6.34.7-ELinOS-146-ipipe)
MSR: 00021032 <ME,CE,IR,DR>  CR: 28000482  XER: 20000000
TASK = c3ba6cb0[71] 'udevd' THREAD: c78e0000
GPR00: 00000000 c790f870 c3ba6cb0 00000001 c790f8b8 00000008 00000000 00000000
GPR08: 00000000 c0370000 00000001 c0370000 5d0fabd2 10033420 10019a6c 00000000
GPR16: 10019328 100194d4 100194c0 1002bad0 10019328 10019474 bfa35428 100192fc
GPR24: 100321f0 00000000 00000000 c649e840 00000000 00000901 00000000 00000000
NIP [c001acfc] add_preempt_count+0x48/0xac
LR [c001ace4] add_preempt_count+0x30/0xac
Call Trace:
Instruction dump:
409e0038 54290024 8009000c 2f800000 40bc0028 48133285 2f830000 419e0068
3d20c037 8009d298 2f800000 409e0058 <0fe00000> 48000050 3d20c037 8009d130
Unable to handle kernel paging request for instruction fetch
Faulting instruction address: 0x00000000
Oops: Kernel access of bad area, sig: 11 [#1]
PREEMPT LTT NESTING LEVEL : 0
ORION
last sysfs file: /sys/devices/platform/gpio-keys-polled/input/input0/uevent
NIP: 00000000 LR: 00000000 CTR: c01c7778
REGS: c790f990 TRAP: 0400   Tainted: G        W   (2.6.34.7-ELinOS-146-ipipe)
MSR: 20009032 <EE,ME,IR,DR>  CR: 28000484  XER: 20000000
TASK = c3ba6cb0[71] 'udevd' THREAD: c78e0000
GPR00: 00000000 c790fa40 c3ba6cb0 00000008 00000008 00000008 c7912804 c0348ba4
GPR08: 00000047 c78a5414 00000000 00000004 28000482 10033420 10019a6c 00000000
GPR16: 10019328 100194d4 100194c0 1002bad0 10019328 10019474 bfa35428 100192fc
GPR24: 100321f0 00000000 c790f618 00200200 00000000 c790fa34 00200200 00000000
NIP [00000000] (null)
LR [00000000] (null)
Call Trace:
Instruction dump:
XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX
Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
Call Trace:
Rebooting in 180 seconds..
INFO: RCU detected CPU 0 stall (t=2500 jiffies)
INFO: RCU detected CPU 0 stall (t=10000 jiffies)
INFO: RCU detected CPU 0 stall (t=17500 jiffies)
INFO: RCU detected CPU 0 stall (t=25000 jiffies)
INFO: RCU detected CPU 0 stall (t=32500 jiffies)
INFO: RCU detected CPU 0 stall (t=40000 jiffies)
System Halted, OK to turn off power
------------[ cut here ]------------
kernel BUG at /opt/elinos-5.1/linux/linux-ppc-2.6.34/mm/vmalloc.c:1228!
Oops: Exception in kernel mode, sig: 5 [#2]
PREEMPT LTT NESTING LEVEL : 0
ORION
last sysfs file: /sys/devices/platform/gpio-keys-polled/input/input0/uevent
NIP: c009b0cc LR: c0013518 CTR: 00000000
REGS: c790f7c0 TRAP: 0700   Tainted: G      D W   (2.6.34.7-ELinOS-146-ipipe)
MSR: 00029032 <EE,ME,CE,IR,DR>  CR: 28000484  XER: 20000000
TASK = c3ba6cb0[71] 'udevd' THREAD: c78e0000
GPR00: 078fe000 c790f870 c3ba6cb0 00001000 00000001 00000001 c9000000 fddff000
GPR08: ffffffff 000000d0 c001018c c790e000 48000488 10033420 10019a6c 00000000
GPR16: 10019328 100194d4 100194c0 1002bad0 10019328 10019474 bfa35428 100192fc
GPR24: c001018c 000000d0 00001000 ffffffff c9000000 fddff000 00000001 00000001
NIP [c009b0cc] __get_vm_area_node+0x68/0x204
LR [c0013518] __ioremap_caller+0x90/0x134
Call Trace:
Instruction dump:
7c9e2378 93e1003c 7cbf2b78 90010044 9261000c 92810010 92a10014 92c10018
92e1001c 93410028 800b000c 5400016e <0f000000> 70a00001 41820030 7c7e0034
Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
Call Trace:
Rebooting in 180 seconds..:
```

Could anybody give me some hints how to approach the problem? What I want is to understand which component of the system (i.e. memory chip, etc.) causes this failure. I will be very happy to hear any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: /opt/elinos-5.1/linux/linux-ppc-2.6.34/drivers/rtc/hctosys.c: unable to open rtc device (rtc0) I think the problem is this! The rtc (driver  for the real time clock) is not working properly, it may be the low temperature affects its behavior?

Answer (score 0):

1. All the OOPS/panic information show the exception happened in udevd context, I think it may be triggered by "/sbin/modprobe -bv of:NioctlTCfsl,mpc5125-ioctl".
   To verify this, you can remove the "/sbin/modprobe -bv of:NioctlTCfsl,mpc5125-ioctl" entry in your root file system to see whether the system can boot up successfully.
2. I guess your platform CPU is PowerPC architecture. If so, the exception vector is 0x700, it means the instruction fetch exception. CPU tried to fetch one instruction from invalid address. The instruction flow is incremented if there are no jump/branch instructions. If option 1 is verified that it is related to "/sbin/modprobe", please check the kernel module to analysis the instruction fetch exception.

Good luck!